several vertices swap X position when Shape key is mirrored, how I can fix it without splitting and mirroring again?
When I apply a 'Mirror Shape Key (Topology)' to a shape key, some vertices swaps their X position with his mirrored vertex generating a not expected behavior even though the vertices aren't affected in the Shape Key. Happens even when I apply the 'Mirror Shape Key (Topology)' to the basis shape key.
basis shape key:

basis with 'Mirror Shape Key (Topology) applied:

'new Shape from mix' (from basis shape key) with 'Mirror Shape Key (Topology)' applied going from 0 to 1:
Note that I don´t anything more than 'Mirror Shape Key (Topology)' in the new Shape key

If I split the model and mirroring it again, it works fine but I have Shape keys created on it and the mirror modifier cannot be applied to a mesh with Shape keys, do solution exists without splitting and mirroring it?

You can apply the mirror modifier with this addon

@Leander Is this a bug? Have indices got muddled somewhere and can they be un-muddled?

I don't know. I irrationally don't trust floats and stick to the mirror modifier as long as possible.
